# Deriving custom exception listener from Symfony default exception listener: What are the correct service arguments?

Tags: symfony, exception

Im trying to implement my custom exception listener that is derived from Symfony's default exception listener. The minimal code is:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener as SymfonyExceptionListener;
namespace MyCompany\MyBundle\EventListener;

class ExceptionListener extends SymfonyExceptionListener {

  public function __construct( $controller, LoggerInterface $logger = null ) {
    parent::__construct( $controller, $logger );
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    // The parent class has priority -128
    return array(
      KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => array( 'onKernelException', -64 ),
    );
  }
}
```

Obviously, I need to inject the controller and the logger into the constructor and this is where my problem starts. According to the documentation, I need to register the service via:

```
services:
  kernel.listener.custom_exception_listener:
    class: MyCompany\MyBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException, priority: -64 }
```

What do I need to put into `arguments: []`? It must be something along the lines `"@controller @logger-service"` but I could not find the correct names anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering custom exception listener in on hand - is just registering some listener. The minimum code here is:

```
class ExceptionListener
{
   public function listenExceptions(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
   {
      // Some event management
   }
}
```

And config:

```
services:
  kernel.listener.custom_exception_listener:
    class: MyCompany\MyBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    tags:
       - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: listenExceptions, priority: -64 }
```

So to register listener you shouldn't extend something or inject services.
In other hand, you might need some services to handle an event (logger or mailer). In that case you should create constructor and inject services that you're going to use.

If you wanna extend Symfony2 `ExceptionListener` (which is Subscriber), `%twig.exception_listener.controller%` and `@logger` are default parameters for Symfony2 exception listener

Comment: You more or less repeated my code but did not answer my question. The reason why I inherit from the default ExceptionListener is that I want to keep 99% percent of its functionality but modify it in 1%. I know how to register the event listener. The code is already in my question. You wrote "In that case you should create constructor and inject services that you're going to use." Oh really? That is exactly what my question is about. What is the correct name (in the YAML file) that need to be put in for the "controller" argument of the constructor of the event listener?

Comment: Added default symfony exception listener parameters to an answer

Comment: Thanks, that all I wanted to know.